# CGO how to pass slice to rust

Tags: go, rust, ffi, cgo

golang

```
input := []uint{1,2,3,4,5,6}
o := C.fixU32_encode((*C.uint)(unsafe.Pointer(&input[0])), C.size_t(len(input)))
return C.GoString(o)
```

c

```
char* fixU32_encode(unsigned int* ptr,size_t length);
```

rust

```
pub extern "C" fn fixU32_encode(ptr: *const u32, length: libc::size_t) -> *const libc::c_char {
    assert!(!ptr.is_null());
    let slice = unsafe {
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, length as usize)
    };
    println!("{:?}", slice);// there will print [1,0,2,0,3,0]
    println!("{:?}", length);
    let mut arr = [0u32; 6];
    for (&x, p) in slice.iter().zip(arr.iter_mut()) {
        *p = x;
    }
    CString::new(hex::encode(arr.encode())).unwrap().into_raw()
}
```

This will be passed in, but the array received by rust is like this
`[1,0,2,0,3,0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go an uint is 64bit (see https://golangbyexample.com/go-size-range-int-uint/). As a result, you are storing 64bit integers in `input`.

The C Code and Rust code treats the `input` now was 32bit unsigned integers (in little endian format). So the first input of 0x1 in 64bit:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

becomes 0x1 and 0x0 respectively. Due to little endian the least significant bits are read first.

You want to be specific in Go to use 32bit using `uint32` or ensure your C code matches the machine dependent integers types in Go.